# What do independent events in probability correspond to while using Venn diagrams.

Tags: probability

What do independent events in probability correspond to while using Venn diagrams.

I find the use of and diagrams in problems for sets of probabilities would be really helpful but when it comes to having two independent events , I could not visualise what the Venn diagram for it would be.

Eg as $P(A\cap B ) = P(A)P(B)$ and so $n(A\cap B)n(S) = n(A)n(B)$ ... But I couldn't really think of connecting the products of cardinality with a Venn diagram. Can someone help me with what the Venn diagram for independent events is (if it even exists....) ??

Comment: I do not know what kind of relation you expect... I mean, the one you wrote is precisely the definition and there is not much else about it. Maybe it would satisfy you to reinterpret it in terms of conditional probabilities: $P(A \mid B) = P(A)$ is equivalent to independence. As a final remark, the expression you wrote in terms of number of elements of the sets only holds when you consider that every element of the sample space has the same probability. However, probabilities can be more general than this.

Comment: @Daniel What I have in mind is, like when for $P(A\cup B)$ we make two circles for A and B, and shading them both can give you an idea of what's going on. Now when a lot of the cases are introduced simultaneously, Venn Diagrams could be really helpful (Atleast for a high schooler like me, maybe in higher studies one gets so acquainted that using venn feels like using your fingers to do addition). And I don't really feel a lot comfortable with it , so was just asking if a Venn diagram representation of it existed

Comment: The best I can do is to expand on the conditional probability interpretation of independence. Let us keep up with the uniform probabilities. Stating that $P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = P(A)$ is saying that the fraction of the sample space that $A$ occupies is the same as the fraction of $B$ that $A \cap B$ occupies. Does this help?

Comment: I like to draw independent events as $A=I\times[0,1]$ and $B=[0,1]\times J$ with some intervals $I$ and $J$, regarding the sample space as the square $[0,1] \times[0,1] $.

Comment: A Venn's diagram helps to illustrate some fundamental properties of set. Given two events $A, B$, we cannot tell they are independent or not if we do not mention the probability measure $P$, i.e. it is a property with respect to a certain probability measure only. So they can be independent under $P$ but dependent under $Q$.